# Perl File::Find::Rule

Tags: perl, file, find, rule

I am trying to copy just the subfolders' names (non-recursively) into an array using [`File::Find::Rule`](http://metacpan.org/module/File::Find::Rule). I also want to exclude the directory names which are mentioned in array `@exclude_dirs`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use Data::Dumper;

my $basedir      = "C:\/Test";
my @exclude_dirs = qw( dir1_excl dir2_excl );

my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule
    ->directory()
  # ->name(@exclude_dirs)->prune->discard, File::Find::Rule->new 
    ->maxdepth(1)
    ->in( $basedir );

print Dumper(\@subdirs);
```

#### Desired Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'dir1',
          'dir2',
          'dir3'
        ]
```

#### Current Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'C:/Test',
          'C:/Test/dir1',
          'C:/Test/dir1_excl',
          'C:/Test/dir2',
          'C:/Test/dir2_excl',
          'C:/Test/dir3'
        ]
```

Comment: `qw` quotes words separated by whitespace. Lose the comma, and add some whitespace.

Comment: Modified the code, but still how would I frame the rule to exclude those

Comment: Honestly, File::Find::Rule is overkill for this. I would use [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) instead.

Comment: @ikegami You're certainly entitled to that opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you were trying for:

```
my @subdirs =
     File::Find::Rule
        ->mindepth(1)
        ->maxdepth(1)
        ->directory
        ->or(
            File::Find::Rule
                ->name(@exclude_dirs)
                ->discard
                ->prune,
            File::Find::Rule
                ->new
          )
        ->in($basedir);
```

Possible optimization:

```
my @subdirs =
     File::Find::Rule
        ->mindepth(1)
        ->maxdepth(1)
        ->or(
            File::Find::Rule
                ->name(@exclude_dirs)
                ->discard
                ->prune,
            File::Find::Rule
                ->directory
          )
        ->in($basedir);
```

That said, all you need is the following:

```
my @subdirs =
    File::Find::Rule
        ->mindepth(1)
        ->maxdepth(1)
        ->not_name(@exclude_dirs)
        ->directory
        ->in($basedir);
```

All of those return full paths, so you'd need to follow up with

```
s{^\Q$basedir\E/}{} for @subdirs;
```

Normally, I'd use FFR instead [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) because using `readdir` is far longer, far more complex and far more error-prone. But in this case, it's borderline.

```
my @subdirs;
{
   my %exclude_dirs = map { $_ => 1 } '.', '..', @exclude_dirs;

   opendir(my $dh, $basedir)
      or die("Can't read dir \"$basedir\": $!\n");

   while (my $fn = readdir($dh)) {
      next if $exclude_dirs{$fn};

      my $qfn = "$basedir/$fn";
      if (!stat($qfn)) {
         warn("Skipping \$qfn\": Can't stat: $!\n");
         next;
      }

      push @subdirs, $fn if -d _;
   }
}
```

Comment: The readdir solution is throwing and error "Bad symbol for dirhandle at `while (local $_ = readdir($basedir)) {`

Comment: Fixed. I haven't tested that one.

Comment: I tried the 3rd File::Find::Rule solution. Its working fine b excluding directories, but its also printing the base dir itself and sub directories with full path. How can I achieve just the name of sub-directories into an array (Check my desired output posted above)

Comment: I missed that you had asked for just the file name. Updated my answer. (Matt Jacob answer is just a copy of mine with the error checking removed. Using a regex is also less efficient than the hash I used.)

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $basedir      = "C:/Test";
my @exclude_dirs = qw(. .. dir1_excl dir2_excl);
my $exclude_pat  = join('|', map { quotemeta } @exclude_dirs);

opendir(my $dh, $basedir) or die $!;
my @subdirs = grep { -d "$basedir/$_" && !/^(?:$exclude_pat)\z/i } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);

print Dumper(\@subdirs);
```

If the directories to exclude aren't as dynamic as they seem in your question, there's no need to build the regular expression at runtime:

```
my @subdirs = grep { -d "$basedir/$_" && !/^(?:\.|\.\.|dir1_excl|dir2_excl)\z/i } readdir($dh);
```